# Pulling Android data usage statistics from settings

Tags: root-access, data-monitoring

Is there a way to pull or display the Android data usage statistics from the settings on a day by day basis? Currently the Usage section in settings shows a range of days but it doesn't show how much was consumed on each day.

The phone is rooted if that helps at all.

Comment: See apps [Google search](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=android+app+daily+data+usage&oq=android+app+for+daily+data+consumption&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0.24442j0j4&client=ms-android-motorola&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Those apps typically only start capturing data from the moment they're installed if I'm not mistaken. I'm looking to retrieve usage data from this past week.

In the future, those apps will be helpful but I didn't have any of those apps installed during the period of time that I need to pull a report.